# How to identify different what epics each PBI in the backlogs list?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

How do you organize your backlog list so that you can identify easily which PBIs are related to which Epic and Feature? In JIRA you have different colors that identify the Epics but in Azure boards, all of them are the same icons..

Would be great if you can share how you organize your backlogs with priorities.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do you organize your backlog list so that you can identify easily which PBIs are related to which Epic and Feature?

In Azure DevOps Backlogs, you can show Parents and Related Link Count as Columns.

[image]

Click Column Options to add columns that you need to show in the backlog.

In Boards, you can show Parents in the card.

[image]

Click the Settings button in the upper right corner. Choose Cards/Fields/Additional fields to add fields that you need to show in the card.

To show which PBIs are related to which Epic and Feature, you can use [queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser).

> In JIRA you have different colors that identify the Epics but in Azure boards, all of them are the same icons.

You can set different colors for work items in Azure DevOps.

[image]

Click the Settings button in the upper right corner. Choose Cards/Styles. Here, you can set card color and title style for different work items according to the rules. Here is an example. I set the work items with priority 1 to light orange. The final result is shown in the picture above.

[image]

Comment: are we able to use the styling rule in the backlogs instead of just in the boards?

Comment: If you have many features with alot of epics, how do you distinguish which backlog items belong to which within the Board or the Backlog view?

Comment: @Rakavy I can't believe that I forgot this! If work items are Parent/Children relationships, in backlog, you can display the work items as a tree form by clicking the "Parents" button in "View Options" at the upper right corner of the page.

Comment: The issue with the Parent Tree is that it wont allow you to prioritize the backlog items when this is activated